# How to check what OS a docker image depends on?

Tags: docker, docker-container, docker-image

I want to extend my jenkins image to have docker installed so it can build a Dockerfile out of a project.
I found a nice install script for docker but only for Ubuntu 64bit. What I need to know is if the parent images of my jenkins image base on Ubuntu 64bit so I can use this install script without any problems.

I used `docker image inspect <imagename>` already but it only yields hashes for former image versions it seems.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
docker run <image-name> cat /etc/*release*
```

It will return the metadata about your image. In the following form.

```
NAME="Amazon Linux"
VERSION="2"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="centos rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux 2"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:2.3:o:amazon:amazon_linux:2"
HOME_URL="https://amazonlinux.com/"
VARIANT_ID="202011171307-al2.470.0"
Amazon Linux release 2 (Karoo)
cpe:2.3:o:amazon:amazon_linux:2
```

Comment: I needed to have cat command also to above: `docker run <image-name> /bin/bash -c "cat /etc/*release"`

Comment: This works for me!!! Thank you~

Comment: Not working on all images because some images dont know cat command: `Unknown option: 'cat'`

Answer (score 9):

In the docker world you'll encounter OSes like Alpine more or less frequently.
Hence its mostly advisable to get contents of the `/etc/os-release` file which will in most scenarios be present.

```sh
# Tomcat 9 running on Alpine OS
docker run -it tomcat:9-alpine cat /etc/os-release

# Tomcat 9 running Debian (buster)
docker run -it tomcat:9 cat /etc/os-release
```

[image: docker base os]

Answer (score 4):

Following command worked `docker run mysql cat /etc/os-release`.

**Output**:

```
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="10"
VERSION="10 (buster)"
VERSION_CODENAME=buster
ID=debian
. . .
```

Answer (score 3):

The fact that your Jenkins is built on an Ubuntu 64 bits or a Fedora 24 or a Debian jessie should not bother you, as it should work anyway.

See

[Run Different Linux OS in Docker Container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112137/run-different-linux-os-in-docker-container)

for more explanations

and also

[Docker container isolation, does it care about underlying Linux OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29911415/docker-container-isolation-does-it-care-about-underlying-linux-os?lq=1)

Anyway, if you want to get the FROM line of the Dockerfile used to build this image,

you can use the docker image

https://hub.docker.com/r/dduvnjak/dockerfile-from-image/

to get the

`FROM UBUNTU`

or

`FROM DEBIAN`

example from

[How to check for Certain Properties in Docker Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45820249/how-to-check-for-certain-properties-in-docker-images/45820326#45820326)

`$ docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock  dduvnjak/dockerfile-from-image  k3ck3c/nethogs | grep FROM`

will show

`FROM alpine:latest`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is currently any docker command that allows you to do that. It seems that the only way is to launch the container and run those commands: [determine OS distribution of a docker image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35689431/determine-os-distribution-of-a-docker-image)

Answer (score 0):

Solution: docker run mysql cat /etc/os-release

Output:

```
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="11"
VERSION="11 (bullseye)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bullseye
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```